# Кириллица в Яндекс-поиск для сайта

Tags: html, яндекс-поиск

Сервис яндекс-поиск выдает неправильную кодировку.

Задал вопрос в техподдержку яндекса, не отвечают уже 3 дня. Может, тут эксперты ответят быстрее.

В общем, установил код на сайт, на английском языке запросы проходят нормально. На русском — проблемы с кодировкой, выводится в 16-битном формате.
Пробовал utf-8 , windows-1251, автоопределение, ничто не спасает.

Скриншот прилагаю:

[img http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1380522512-clip-38kb.png?nocache=1](http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1380522512-clip-38kb.png?nocache=1)

Answer (score 1):

Давайте по порядку.

Не работал с Яндекс.Поиск, но судя по скриншоту, проблема в том, что строка проходит URL-кодирование. Чтобы понять на каком этапе это проходит, необходимо немного больше информации. Опишите способ, которым вы добавляете поиск на страницу, покажите код вставки, после каких действий происходит преобразование строки и т.д.

Пинать можно, но в мягких тапках.

Answer (score 1):

Поступил ответ от саппорта яндекса.

Проблема была в том, что яндекс ссылался на зеркало без www. 
А в .htaccess стоял редирект на www.

После того, как прописал www перед доменом, все заработало.